# How to unselect the current section

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to set a bibliography on the end of a presentation and to unselect the current section which is the last one.

How to unselect the current section please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put `\appendix` in front of your bibliography, this should make navigation disappear:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}

\begin{document}
    \section{1}
        \begin{frame}
            stuff
        \end{frame}
    \section{2}
        \begin{frame}
            more stuff
        \end{frame}
    \appendix
    \begin{frame}
        more stuff
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]